# Update EF record will not affected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 4 tables that 2 of them are just for insert tracking data of 2 others.
I want to insert into 2 tables and update data in the 2 other tables.

This is my code:

```
using (var context = new AutoPackEntities())
{
    var myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JRDocument>(jsonObject);

    var activity = context.NetworkActivities
                .Include(c => c.Document)
                .Include(c => c.NetworkActivityTracking)
                .Include(c => c.Document.DocumentsTracking)
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == myJsonObject.Activity.Id);

    DocumentTracking myDocumentTrack = new DocumentTracking();
    NetworkActivityTracking  myActivityTrack =new NetworkActivityTracking();

    myActivityTrack = CreateActivityTrack(activity);
    myDocumentTrack = CreateDocumentTrack(activity.Document);

    activity.NetworkActivityTracking.Add(myActivityTrack);
    activity.Document.DocumentsTracking.Add(myDocumentTrack);

    activity = myJsonObject.Activity;
    activity.Document = myJsonObject.Document;

    context.DocumentsTracking.Add(myDocumentTrack);
    context.NetworkActivitiesTracking.Add(myActivityTrack);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code returns OK and does not throw any errors, and I can tell that insert data will be done, but the update does not change anything, and the data is what it was before.

Data should insert into these tables:

```
NetworkActivityTracking, DocumentTracking
```

and should update these tables:

```
NetworkActivities, Document
```

Comment: Try to fetch entities without caching using .AsNoTracking():var activity = context.NetworkActivities
                .Include(c => c.Document)
                .Include(c => c.NetworkActivityTracking)
                .Include(c => c.Document.DocumentsTracking)
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == myJsonObject.Activity.Id).AsNoTracking()

Comment: activity = myJsonObject.Activity; will create a new object not in the context.  So it will be inserted and not updated. You should map all properties of your "myJsonObject.Activity" to the properties of "activity"

Comment: moreover, you have some lines of code that re not useful (you create empty objects and then you overwrite these objects)

Comment: insert data is correct in right place. 'activity = myJsonObject.Activity' is not empty because i take data from Jason and my class is  "myJsonObject" so i take "Activity" class of this class and put on my activity context

Comment: i added AsNoTracking() but not affected